# How to load URL on UITableViewCell touch

Tags: arrays, uitableview, xcode4

New at this, just trying to make a link load if a certain UITableView cell is touched.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
  NSArray *deals = [dic objectForKey:@"deals"];
  NSDictionary *dealOne = [deals objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *url = [dealOne objectForKey:@"url"];

  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

  if([touch isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
  {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];
    cell.center = location;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
  }
  NSLog(@"TABLECELL TOUCHED");
}
```

Comment: Why you are using touchesBegan , UITableView already have a touch detection delegate which is - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.In this method you can simply call the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the following. In this case, I wanted to have a link load when the cell was touched for "finalDealOne." When the cell is double-tapped, the link loads.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
  NSArray *deals = [dic objectForKey:@"deals"];
  NSDictionary *dealOne = [deals objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *title = [dealOne objectForKey:@"title"];
  NSString *finalDealOne = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Deal One:\n\n''%@''\n\nDouble tap here to redeem offer.",title];

  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(finalDealOne)];
  tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

  [cell addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
}
```

To make this work, I included the following reference:

```
 - (void)finalDealOne
 { 
    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
    NSArray *deals = [dic objectForKey:@"deals"];
    NSDictionary *dealOne = [deals objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *url = [dealOne objectForKey:@"url"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 }
```